# Why didn't someone entertain the idea of creating clone army of force sensitives?

Tags: star-wars

There was never a scarcity of force sensitives provided there was successful cloning technology. But still, Jedi order was eager to find new force sensitives.

The original clone army was designed using modified DNA of a bounty hunter. It could be DNA of a force sensitive being. Whoever ordered the clone army didn't think about making such inevitable army. Why?

After execution of Order 66, Yoda and Kenobi also didn't think about this. Why? An army of Yoda could always crush the Galactic Empire without a doubt.

Comment: Can midiclorians be cloned? And if they can, will a clone Jedi automatically have the same amount of midiclorians as the original?

Comment: [Starkiller](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_%28clone%29) was a clone of Garen Malek. Both were powerful Force users. There are also Jorus C'baoth and the clone of Luke as mentioned in one of the other answers.

Comment: @Xantec Midi-chlorians are biological entities. There's no reason why they can't be cloned. Although, there's chance of exception, but phantom42 has given solid data. So, its possible. As Starkiller was also powerful force user, Midi-chlorians count could be assumed same (slightly more or less)..

Comment: @Chad I am talking about ARMY. If it'd happen, it'd be popular event.

Comment: @phantom42 Thanks. It says that creation of clone army of force sensitive is possible.

Comment: Probably because a Jedi clone army could potentially be uncontrollable. Joruus C'baoth was a little insane, after all: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Joruus_C%27baoth

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are only a handful of races who possess cloning technology. Of those, the Kaminoans were the only ones that had large cloning facilities. Those, of course, were the same used to create the clone army for and during the Clone Wars.

The new Empire knew that such technology could be devastating should it fall into the wrong (or would it be right?) hands. To prevent this, they seized control of the planet and the facilities. From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kamino):

> The end of the Clone Wars resulted not only in the near destruction of the Jedi Order, but also the rise of the Galactic Empire in the place of the fallen Republic. Seeking to secure the vital cloning facilities that were responsible for providing the Empire with the clones that helped to secure Emperor Palpatine's rise to ultimate power, Imperial control was firmly established upon Kamino through force of arms.

But the Kaminoans *did* breed a new army to fight against the Empire. This army was wiped out by a detachment of the 501st legion.

> Although Kamino would continue to grow more stormtroopers for the Empire, a small group of Kaminoans grew resentful of the Empire's treatment of Kamino as a virtual military police state. In response to the Imperial presence on their world, the Kaminoans launched a covert rebellion against the Empire by discreetly breeding a new army of clones, all based on the genetic template of Jango Fett. Unlike the first Clone army that had been bred for the Republic, the newest generation of clones were engineered with absolute loyalty to Kamino.

So, to answer your question more directly: Yoda, Kenobi and other surviving Jedi might have had the idea to have a new clone army bred, but the facilities to do so were under Imperial control.

The original clone army was ordered by Papaltine by way of Sifo-Dyas. He clearly DID think about the possibility of a new army (Jedi, Force Users or otherwise) and had Imperial forces take control of the facilities needed to breed such an army.

Comment: Nice answer. But, it answers only one part of Yoda & Kenobi.

Comment: What? There is no documentation either way as far as I have read stating whether or not they DID ever think of cloning themselves. But here is specific reason/evidence of why neither one COULD clone themselves into an army.

Comment: I meant one part of question which is related with Yoda & Kenobi.

Comment: I've expanded the answer, but I felt it was already pretty clear that Papaltine HAD thought about the cloning facilities being turned against him to create a new army. That's why he had it taken over.

Answer (score 8):

They did.  Darth Plagious was working on creating an army of creature that would be commanded directly through the force by him.

On top of that there where:

[Force-sensitive Stormtroopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force-sensitive_stormtrooper)

> Although the experimental stormtroopers were impressive to both
>   Palpatine and Vader, they were also too impressive as far as Vader was
>   concerned; the Sith Lord judged them to be too dangerous to himself
>   and his master. His fears were validated when the troopers staged an
>   unanticipated insurrection, thus revealing their true loyalty to the
>   one who trained them—the disillusioned Emperor's Hand Sheyvan.

And [ShadowTroopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowtrooper)

> Shadowtroopers were stormtrooper-Dark Jedi hybrid soldiers created by
>   the Dark Jedi Desann and Imperial Admiral Galak Fyyar on behalf of
>   Lord Hethrir's Empire Reborn. Similar to the Reborn soldiers, Desann
>   used the Valley of the Jedi to imbue stormtroopers with Force powers.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is a Jedi named Jorus C'baoth who was cloned. The clone was mentally unstable.

Also Luke was cloned (the name of the clone was Luuke) and same thing has happened, a mentally unstable clone emerged

edit: as phantom explained, there is a successful clone, however before that succesful clone there were lots of failures: [Starkiller clone](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_%28clone%29) therefore creating a succesful clone of a jedi may not always be possible, especially without the resources like those of the Empire.

Comment: Not all clones are unstable. [Starkiller](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_%28clone%29) was a clone of Garen Malek. He was a powerful Force user and had no particular mental instabilities.

Comment: Hmm maybe that can be explained by the different technologies used. For Joruus and Luuke the Spaarti cloning tech was used, while for Starkiller they used the Kaminoan tech. Still the wookiepedia says that most of the clones were aberrant

Comment: Yes, but he was one of a few. Cloning force-sensitives was a very inconsistent art

Comment: To add to the idea of inconsistency, [Dorsk 81](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dorsk_81) was one in a long line of clones, and he was the _first_ to show force sensitivity.  Dorsk 82 and 83 apparently also showed sensitivity, and I also read somewhere else that they then worked to make sure force sensitivity remained a part of the genetic line, but I can't find a concrete source to back that part up.