# Why does Kota think Jedi can't be cloned?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the Force Unleashed II, Rahm Kota states that it is impossible to clone a jedi.  This is clearly false, since

> Galen Marek was cloned.

What makes cloning jedi any different from cloning something else? Was Kota perhaps only referring to the specific type of cloning where clones were grown rapidly, matured quickly, and had memories implanted in them. Is there something about force sensitive individuals that makes them difficult to clone?

Comment: *"Is there something about force sensitive individuals that makes them difficult to clone?"*  'Midi-chlorians' ..

Comment: possible dup.: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21831/why-didnt-someone-entertain-the-idea-of-creating-clone-army-of-force-sensitives

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the problem with clones is that they get a kind of shock when all the midi-chlorians rush in. Making them mentaly unstable. The work around is to either do as the Kaminos do and grow them from children at an accelerated rate. Or as Grand Admiral Thrawn does and use Yslamirs to block out the force during the entire cloning process.