# What did the Kaminoans do, other than making the Clone Army?

Tags: star-wars

It seems like the entire purpose of the Kaminoan people is to sit in their waterworld and wait for an order of clones.

Dex, the fry-cook who Obi-Wan talks with even refers to the Kaminoans simply as "*cloners*", suggesting it's a pretty big part of their identity.

Finally, in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21831/why-didnt-someone-entertain-the-idea-of-creating-clone-army-of-force-sensitives), it's stated that some renegade Kaminoans started making clones to fight against the burgeoning Empire.

Literally all I've see of these earbud weirdos is cloning. Sure, that's all the canon seems to get into, but surely the Kaminoans did more than that? Did they receive many clone orders and busied their time with that? Did they clone each other when there wasn't an order for clones?

**Is cloning only a small part of their culture, and they're actually very interesting and just happen to have a great proficiency in cloning?**

Comment: Related, not a dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/74350/31936

Comment: Disney canon is now just "Kaminoans made the clone army, yay" and that's about it. Legends canon (though mostly unsourced as of yet on Wookiepedia, which is why this is a comment and not an answer) seems to say that the Kaminoans were pushed to the brink of extinction by a flood and the only way they were able to survive was through great advances in genetics and cloning. So it's quite possible that the Kaminoans we see in AotC are all that remain of their species, and all they have left is their cloning technology.

Comment: @Null - Are you sure it's not a dupe? It offers an explanation regarding what the Kaminoans do when they're not making clone armies.

Comment: @Valorum That question (and answer) focus on clone armies, but this question is asking about what else the Kaminoans do besides cloning. Additionally, this question seems to be limited to canon ("that's all the canon seems to get into") but (a) the other question doesn't specify any limitation between canon or Legends and (b) my answer to it is based heavily on Legends. It's close, though.

Comment: @Null - Sigh. That old chestnut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloning and genetic manipulation appear to be the Kaminoan's main *export* trade. The two primary **canon** factbooks ([Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) and [Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars)) do offer some additional info about what they get up to when they're not making clone *armies*.

---

When they aren't making armies, the Kaminoans export clones for *enforced slavery*. They also develop exotic weaponry and (apparently) have something of a tourist trade, although this may be intended facetiously, given the planet's evident remoteness.

> ***Kaminoans make precision tools and weapons***
>
> and
>
> ***Underwater Tourism - Take a journey under the stormy seas in a
> submarine***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)</sup></sub>

and

> *Over the years, the **Kaminoans developed cloning laboratories on their
> homeworld and their clone creations began appearing on outlying world,
> such as the mining planet of Subterrel.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars)</sup></sub>

---

The (alas no longer canon) [Inside the Worlds of Star Wars: Attack of the Clones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inside_the_Worlds_of_Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones) and [Star Wars: Attack of the Clones The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones_The_Visual_Dictionary) factbooks also offer the following snippets of info.

> *Kamino is a remote and inhospitable world covered in one unending
> ocean. Located in a dwarf satellite galaxy beyond the Outer Rim, **the
> planet receives very little traffic and only as much trade as is
> necessary to supply the basic needs of its inhabitants, the amphibious
> Kaminoans.** This highly intelligent race has specialized in the
> high-skill, value-added industry of human, alien, and creature
> cloning, **supplying a select client base with workers, private security
> forces, and a range of unusual, one-off requests.** The Kaminoans live
> in stilt-cities scattered across the planet's watery surface, the
> majority of which are devoted to cloning projects. The Kaminoans only
> rarely receive visitors: The remoteness of the planet and its
> extensive rainy season deters all but the occasional representative of
> a clone purchasing authority.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Inside the Worlds of Star Wars: Attack of the Clones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inside_the_Worlds_of_Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones)</sup></sub>

and

> *When a global climate shift flooded their planet, the Kaminoans were
> forced to adapt. **They developed cloning technology and practised
> selective breeding to keep their race alive.** As a result of the
> hardships endured during the Great Flood, the Kaminoans have an
> austere, non-materialist outlook. They are outwardly polite, yet
> behind this lurks an extreme intolerance of physical imperfection. **The
> Kaminoans are reliant on certain outworld technologies and raw
> materials to maintain their advanced society, so they use their
> cloning abilities to produce goods for export**.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Attack of the Clones The Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones_The_Visual_Dictionary)</sup></sub>